# How to mock laravel HasOne relation from eloquent?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, mocking, has-one, eloquent-relationship

I have an issue with mocking eloquent HasOne relation for unit testing purposes.

This is the tricky part:

```php
$save->relationTable()->create([
    'field_1' => 'value_1',
    'field_2' => 'value_2',
    'field_3' => 'value_3',
]);
```

Relation in the model:

```php
public function relationTable(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(RelationTable::class);
}
```

Particularly error is:

> Received  Mockery_4_Illuminate_Database_Eloquent_Relations_HasOne::create(), but no expectations were specified

If anyone knows...

Comment: in you unit test you need to set what is expected to happen so it can show you that  it worked or not.

Comment: Sure, do you know how to set the expectation for $save->relationTable()->create()?
I know for find, create, update etc. But, I am struggling with relations.

Comment: Is there a reason you're mocking Eloquent rather than just hitting the database (and using the `RefreshDatabase` trait if necessary)?

Answer (score 0):

```
shouldReceive('RelationTable')->once();
```

You should end your Mockery with an expected output, otherwise you can't tell if your test worked or not.